# DevStack Installation - Failed to discover available identity versions when contacting http://IP/identity. Attempting to parse version from URL

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, openstack, devstack, keystone

I am trying to install Devstack on Ubuntu 18.04 [according to this tutorial](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/). I created the user `stack` and the file `local.conf` with the following content:

```
[[local|localrc]]
ADMIN_PASSWORD=secret
DATABASE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
RABBIT_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
```

When I run `./stack`, I am getting the following error:

```
WARNING py.warnings [None req-d71fb2ee-2193-40d0-b1df-862dae6292c6 None None] /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pycadf/identifier.py:72: UserWarning: Invalid uuid: RegionOne. To ensure interoperability, identifiers should be a valid uuid.
  'identifiers should be a valid uuid.' % (value)))

INFO keystone.cmd.bootstrap [None req-d71fb2ee-2193-40d0-b1df-862dae6292c6 None None] Created region RegionOne
INFO keystone.cmd.bootstrap [None req-d71fb2ee-2193-40d0-b1df-862dae6292c6 None None] Created public endpoint http://192.168.131.133/identity
INFO keystone.cmd.bootstrap [None req-d71fb2ee-2193-40d0-b1df-862dae6292c6 None None] Created admin endpoint http://192.168.131.133/identity
+./stack.sh:main:1084                      create_keystone_accounts
+lib/keystone:create_keystone_accounts:314  local admin_project
++lib/keystone:create_keystone_accounts:315  oscwrap project show admin -f value -c id
++functions-common:oscwrap:2315             local xtrace
+++functions-common:oscwrap:2316             set +o
+++functions-common:oscwrap:2316             grep xtrace
++functions-common:oscwrap:2316             xtrace='set -o xtrace'
++functions-common:oscwrap:2317             set +o xtrace
Failed to discover available identity versions when contacting http://192.168.131.133/identity. Attempting to parse version from URL.
Could not find versioned identity endpoints when attempting to authenticate. Please check that your auth_url is correct. Not Found (HTTP 404)
++functions-common:oscwrap:2334             return 1
+lib/keystone:create_keystone_accounts:315  admin_project=
+lib/keystone:create_keystone_accounts:1   exit_trap
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:489                  local r=1
++./stack.sh:exit_trap:490                  jobs -p
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:490                  jobs=
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:493                  [[ -n '' ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:499                  '[' -f /tmp/tmp.8Vq4sCbYzU ']'
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:500                  rm /tmp/tmp.8Vq4sCbYzU
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:504                  kill_spinner
+./stack.sh:kill_spinner:399               '[' '!' -z '' ']'
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:506                  [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:507                  echo 'Error on exit'
Error on exit
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:509                  type -p generate-subunit
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:510                  generate-subunit 1589219267 290 fail
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:512                  [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:515                  /usr/bin/python3.6 /opt/stack/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2020-05-11-175237.txt for details
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:524                  exit 1
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you running this inside a VM or your own system? Please refer to this once https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/networking.html

Answer (score 0):

I did two things to solve that. First, inactive UFW (`systemctl stop ufw`). Second, modify the `local.conf` putting the password in each of the lines, something like this:

```
ADMIN_PASSWORD=secret
DATABASE_PASSWORD=secret
RABBIT_PASSWORD=secret
SERVICE_PASSWORD=secret
```

I'm using Ubuntu (ubuntu-18.04.5-live-server-amd64) and basically I'm doing this:

```
sudo useradd -s /bin/bash -d /opt/stack -m stack
echo "stack ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" | sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/stack
sudo su - stack
git clone https://opendev.org/openstack/devstack
cd devstack
echo -e "[[local|localrc]]\nADMIN_PASSWORD=secret\nDATABASE_PASSWORD=secret\nRABBIT_PASSWORD=secret\nSERVICE_PASSWORD=secret" >> local.conf
export XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland
nohup ./stack.sh &
```

If you are installing on a VM is important to add enought ram memory and cpu, at least 2 cores and 8GB of ram.